# Passing an array of struct from C# managed to C++ unmanage and get the changes

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged

There are no luck to find a solution for simple task, please help me to find it out.
Basically I want to pass an array of struct and get back the struct values change from unmanaged code. Here are my code:

C++:

```
struct CPT {
    const char* Value1;
    const char* Value2;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int ToError(CPT* cpts, const int length) {
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    cpts[i].Value1 = "a";
    cpts[i].Value2 = "b";
}
return length;
```

}

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CPT
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string Value1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string Value2;
}

public class Program
{        
    [DllImport("CUDALib.dll")]
    unsafe public static extern int ToError([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out] CPT[] cpts, int length);

    unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cptList = new List<CPT>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            CPT c;
            c.Value1 = $"1000{i}";
            c.Value2 = $"2000{i}";
            cptList.Add(c);
        }
        var errors = new Error[cptList.Count];
        var cpts = cptList.ToArray();
        var result = ToError(cpts, cptList.Count);
    }
}
```

EDITED:
Got it works now, I changed C++ struct to char array, then instead of change array elements property, I assigned array elements itself.
C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ByValTStrTest
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string Value;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string Value2;
}
[DllImport("CUDALib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int CallByValTStr([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref ByValTStrTest model);

    [DllImport("CUDALib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int CallByValTStrArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 2), Out] ByValTStrTest[] model, int length);

var m1 = new LPSTRTest { Value = "00000" };
        var m2 = new ByValTStrTest { Value = "0000", Value2 = "2222" };
        var m3 = new ByValTStrTest[] {
            new ByValTStrTest{ Value = "0000", Value2="2222" },
            new ByValTStrTest{ Value = "1111", Value2="3333" }
        };

        var result = CallLPSTR(ref m1);
        result = CallByValTStr(ref m2);
        result = CallByValTStrArray(m3, m3.Length);
```

C++:

```
struct ByValTStrTest {
    char Value[5];
    char Value2[5];
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CallByValTStr(ByValTStrTest model) {
    if (strcmp(model.Value, "0000") == 0) {
        model = { "1111", "3333" };
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CallByValTStrArray(ByValTStrTest* model, int length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        model[i] = { "4444", "4444" };
    }   
    return 1;
 }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please explain what "no luck" means - are there any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your response @nikita, actually if I change UnmanagedType to ByValTStr, then will run success but get array struct values with special characters: ,ºÓ®ÿ\u007f, ...
If I use UnmanagedType LPStr then got "CSharp has stopped working" crash.
Sorry, Are there anyway to place screenshot here?

Comment: The original struct declaration has a nasty memory management problem.  The marshaller has to do something with those strings, it will try to release them and that is not going to turn out well.  You have to declare them as IntPtr instead to stop the marshaller from being too helpful.  Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to recover the strings.  It is very unclear what additional help you need if char[5] is good enough to get the job done.